# Fetching position of element when set to auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to fetch the position (using jQuery or normal js) of an element when you set the margin properties to auto.

This is what I mean: 
Index.html

```
<div class="new_element">
       The new element 
</div>
```

Index.css

```
.new_element {
      max-width: 750px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
 }
```

*I styled my CSS that way so that the div will be centralized and not fill up the whole window on a system > 750px. But it will start to scale down for lower screen sizes and will eventually fill the whole window on a phone*

Index.js

//now I want to get the rendered position that the browser automatically set it at. I did this:

```
$('.new_element').position()
```

But I got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ".new_element".position is not a function.

What I think is that if you do not explicitly set a left and top properties, you will not be able to fetch them from the Dom.

Is there a hack? A way I can achieve this?

Comment: My jQuery version is 3.1.0. The .postion() method works when I set the left and top properties to actual values e.g. 45px and 306px. It fetches them. But if I set it to auto, it will throw an error

Comment: Do you really need to add a js for that? or you can use @media query in css!

Comment: The js is not for responsiveness. I actually use @media queries in my CSS. I need to fetch the rendered left and top cos I want to do something with them

Comment: ah, okey, try offset if position is not working

Comment: Same error with .offset(). tried it already

Comment: try using a different version of js

Comment: Use this <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Your above code works fine - **[`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)** will indeed correctly grab the `top` and `left` values of elements that have their `margin` set to `auto`. The `8px` you see in the following example is coming from `<body>`, and is added by the browser's user agent stylesheet:

```js
console.log($('.new_element').position());
```

```css
.new_element {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="new_element">
  The new element
</div>
```

It's worth noting that `.position()` was introduced in jQuery 1.2.6, and the error will show for jQuery versions less than that:

```js
console.log($('.new_element').position());
```

```css
.new_element {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="new_element">
  The new element
</div>
```

Comment: My jQuery version is 3.1.0. The .postion() method works when I set the left and top properties to actual values e.g. 45px and 306px. It fetches them. But if I set it to auto, it will throw an error

Comment: I tried with the CDN and it still didn't work. The problem shouldn't be from my codes then. Let me try updating my browser

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys. Apparently, the code was correct all along.
I forgot the "$" for selecting nodes.

I did

```
("new_element").position();
```

Instead of

```
$("new_element").position();
```